# Should I change the Vendor file in magento ver 2.3.5 p2 for customization in sales order view page

Tags: magento2.3, admin, magento2.3.5-p2, sales-order-view

I've to show the product thumbnail image in Admin order overview page in Magento 2.3.2P2
I am looking to customize default.phtml file of vendor module.

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phptml
```

my required code is as below -

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
?>
<?php /** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $block */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr>
<?php $i = 0;
$columns = $block->getColumns();
$lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>

<td>
<?php $product = $_item->getProduct();?>
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?>

<?php $imagewidth=125;
$imageheight=125;
$imageHelper = $objectManager->get(‘\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image’);
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, ‘small_image’)->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
?>
<img src=”<?php echo $image_url;?>” />
</td>

<?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass) : ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<td class=”<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ‘ last’ : ‘’) ?>”>
<?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

but I am worried that after changing in vendor folder shall affect the future upgrade.
Please suggest best way to achieve this.

I want something lke the below the image.
[image]

Also I need to make clickable the product name and it should be redirect on the respective product page of ordered items.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not change the files from **vendor** directly as they will be lost when you do upgrade Magento in the future. You should override that phtml file in your custom module.

Assume the Vendor name is `TuVan` and the module name is `Sales`, take the following steps:

Step 1: Create `app/code/TuVan/Sales/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'TuVan_Sales', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create `app/code/TuVan/Sales/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TuVan_Sales">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create `app/code/TuVan/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">TuVan_Sales::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 4: Copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`
to    `app/code/TuVan/Customer/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`

Step 5: Make your changes in your custom phtml file which added in above step: `app/code/TuVan/Customer/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`

Step 6: Run setup upgrade command to install and enable the module:

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Step 7: Run compilation code command:
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Step 8: Run deploy static content command:
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You are done.